# Java PrintWriter File Overwrite

Tags: java, file, io, printwriter, writer

I want to write into a file using UTF-16 so I use PrintWriter(file,"UTF-16"), but then it deletes everything in the file, I could use FileWriter(file,true), but then it wouldn't be in UTF-16, and there apparently isn't a constructor for PrintWriter like PrintWriter(Writer,Charset,boolean append);

What should I do?

Comment: You could read in everything first, update that data, then rewrite it to the "new" file?

Comment: @tima: It's not a duplicate of that, as far as I can see. Nothing in there handles appending *and* specifying the encoding.

Comment: @KenReid appending to a file is a pretty mainstream thing to want to do. It should never be necessary to slurp a file up then rewrite it from the start. It would often be inefficient. In some cases the file wouldn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaDoc for `FileWriter` says:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an `OutputStreamWriter` on a `FileOutputStream`.

So you can do:

```
 Writer writer = new PrintWriter(
     new OutputStreamWriter(
           new FileOutputStream(filename, true),
           StandardCharsets.UTF16));
```

You might want to include `BufferedOutputStream` in there too for maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Use `OutputStreamWriter` with a UTF-16 charset, wrapping a `FileOutputStream` opened with append=true. Alternatives, use `Files.newBufferedWriter`:

```
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(
        Paths.of("filename.txt"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_16,
        StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using

```
new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true), "UTF-16"));
```